# Position sticky not working with body{ overflow-x: hidden; }

Tags: css, css-position

I am trying to use bootstrap's sticky header. But when I added `body {overflow-x: hidden; }` it stopped working.

Now I seen on different pages that `position: sticky` with it's parent having `overflow` set to something else as `visible` not showing up, is (or was) a common problem. But all of the posts were like 1 year old. Like this post: "[Position Sticky with overflow-x set for parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502296/position-sticky-with-overflow-x-set-for-parent-div)"

Is there a solution by now? Since bootstrap 4 started using it, I would think that it's more supported right now.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  if($('body').css('overflow-x') !== "hidden"){
    $('body').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
  } else {
    $('body').css('overflow-x', 'unset');
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  top: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

span{
  font-size: 15px;
}

button{
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 40px);
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

article {
  height: 200vw;
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Scroll down.. <br><span>and toggle the button</span></h1>
  <button>toggle body{overflow-x;}</button>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Link#1</li>
      <li>Link#2</li>
      <li>Link#3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article>
    Some content...
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot use it by now.
It is still only partially supported in some browsers.

When you want to know how far it is with this feature, I can advise you to check it on caniuse.com.

Sticky Feature: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: Oh, but then how does it work on my chrome, and I have seen kinda big websites use the `sticky-top` class from bootstrap, so that makes me think that it would be somewhat supported..

Comment: They are probably using JS in addition. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info.  Then I guess I can't use the sticky class. I think then I will just use the fixed-position when scrolled over 100vh off the page.

Comment: A year later and `position: sticky` is no longer experimental with good cross browser (minus IE).

Answer (score 2):

#### UPDATE:

This has been successfully tested on Safari v12.0.2, Firefox v64.0, and Chrome v71.0.3578.98

Added `position: -webkit-sticky;` for Safari.

---

The **simple solution** is to have only `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body and NOT the html element. [Here is the amazing comment](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/865#issuecomment-379106819) buried in the discussion on making the spec clearer regarding overflow and position sticky that helped me to figure this out.

So **make sure to remove it from the html element** and also any ancestor elements of the element you want to be sticky. I posted about the ancestor issue in more depth here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116585/6502003.

I have tested this on Firefox, Chrome, & Safari. Make sure to prefix for Safari as well.

I copied your snippet here with the adjustment that I mentioned and it works in both scenarios when you toggle on and off `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  if($('body').css('overflow-x') !== "hidden"){
    $('body').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
  } else {
    $('body').css('overflow-x', 'unset');
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  top: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

span{
  font-size: 15px;
}

button{
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}

nav {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 40px);
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

article {
  height: 200vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Scroll down.. <br><span>and toggle the button</span></h1>
  <button>toggle body{overflow-x;}</button>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Link#1</li>
      <li>Link#2</li>
      <li>Link#3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article>
    Some content...
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I changed with  `$('body, html').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');` does not works.

Answer (score -1):

There is still no native solution to this problem.

However, I wrote a fallback script for these cases:
[fl_sticky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fl_sticky)