# Why would overflowX affects position: sticky

Tags: css

**NOTE: the suggested answer has nothing to do with my question and DOES NOT answer my question.** if you are looking for real, quality answer please see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116725/13304024
- [body { overflow-x: hidden; } breaks position: sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095596/body-overflow-x-hidden-breaks-position-sticky)

Unfortunately, most mods/people who vote don't even read the post, they just want to hit "the quota".

---

Original question:

I know one of the requirements in order for `position: sticky` to work is parent shouldn't have `overflow` property (hidden/auto). but why if a parent has `overflow-x: hidden|auto` it also breaks `sticky`? (which scrolls on Y-axis)  please see the codepen.io

```
  overflow-x: auto;  // won't work
  overflow-x: visible;  // works
  overflow-x: hidden;  // won't work
```

is there a way to make `overflow-x: hidden` and `position: sticky` work together?
Note: the scroll element need to be window, not an internal dive

https://codepen.io/kossel/pen/GRXKLep

Comment: If you apply `overflow-x: auto;` or `overflow-x: hidden;` only to `body` (instead of `html, body`), then I see no problem in the codepen

Comment: yeah, that too, wondering why in general overflow-X would affect it, and even worse why only if I set both HTML and body would break lol

Comment: Take a look at this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116725/13304024

Comment: the suggested answer has nothing to do with my question and DOES NOT answer my question. stackoverflow.com/a/54116725/13304024 does